# iOS - Developing multiplayer games using GameCenter?

Tags: ios, gamekit

How can I implement & test a multiplayer (turn-based) game using GameKit? Here are the problems I'm facing:

- There are no other matches connected to the sandbox, so I don't get any callbacks from macth finder.
- Xcode allows only 1 instance of the simulator to run, so how can I have 2 clients connected?

Some suggestions would be great on testing multiplayer GameKit based games.

**EDIT:**

I have an instance of the app running on device. another on simulator, and I still can't find a match.

```
    // I call this code on both clients after authentication is successful
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;

    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
    {
        // Process the error.
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else if (match != nil)
    {
        self.myMatch = match;
        match.delegate = self;
        if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
        {
              self.matchStarted = YES;
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two devices for testing because the simulator doesn't get any callbacks. Also, if you use auto-match give the Game Center servers a few minutes to update before you search for an auto-match game on the second devices.